# Delete or Revert git commit in git repo server

Tags: git

One of my team member committed and pushed so large and many files at once (**5 Gbyte**) on git server accidentally. It's one commit. 
And every other team members can not get the git update because it's too slow.(maybe takes 5~6 hours or more). So I think we can not delete the commit on local machines because we can not update the commit yet. (git revert, git reset etc.) Unfortunately, she got off work, so we can not access her local machine.

But, we can access the git repo server using shell.

```
project3.git
```

and the folder.

```
HEAD  config  description  hooks  info  objects  packed-refs  refs
```

So if it's possible, we want to revert or remove the commit or the file using shell command on the server directly. Then our team memebers do not need to get the update. 
Is there any way to do that?

**Update** : We know the commit name. ex) `33aedaf55e`

Comment: first check `git log` and see the latest commit name

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, I added the answer on the thread.

Comment: is this is bad commit that has 5 GB of files. or the one before that ?

Comment: the commit, 5G files commit I want to delete.

Comment: Is the 5G commit is the latest commit that has been pushed to git ?

Comment: right. the last commit. :)

Comment: Okay good. jsut run the following command to revert back to the previous commit.
`git reset --hard HEAD^ `

Comment: on the local shell or server shell?

Comment: the machine from where you pushed that 5G file commit.

Comment: Say you have this, where C is your HEAD

    A-B-C
            ↑
        master

You want to **nuke commit C and never see it again**.  You do this:

    git reset --hard HEAD~1 or git reset --hard HEAD^

The result is:

     
    A-B
        ↑
    master

Now B is the HEAD.  Because you used `--hard`, your files are reset to their state at commit B.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109432/discussion-between-muhammad-shoaib-and-jinbom-heo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE:** Before you do anything, you should **back up a copy** of the remote repository!

If you want to reset the branch in the remote repo:
In the remote repo, show recent history: `git log -3`

```
* 33aedaf - (HEAD, master) commit with big file
* f18fd52 -  some other commit
* 160c78f - another commit
```

Set the branch ref (assuming master here) to the previous commit: `git update-ref refs/heads/master f18fd52`
After this, doing `git fetch` on the master branch will not fetch the big file. What we did was similar to a `git reset --hard f18fd52`.

The big file is still stored in the remote repo though. You could list unreachable objects: `git fsck --unreachable`
And remove all unreachable objects: `git gc --prune=all`. Note that this will remove alll unreachable objects, so make sure the branch pointers look okay first.

Note that what we did was essentially rewriting history. If someone had already pulled the commit with the huge file and started working on it, new issues may arise when he tries to push his commit, so you should probably inform all colleagues who work with the repo about what you have done.